# Quasi-Convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, locally-convex-spaces

Can I get the conclusion that the function of matrix $P$ and $Q$

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{tr}\left( PQ\right)
\end{equation}
is a quasi-concave function for $P>0$, and $Q>0$?

It is true for the scalar case $xy$ if $x>0$ and $y>0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Modified after the question was changed.

For dimensions $n\geq 2$ the statement is false:

take $P_1=Q_1=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 1 \end{array}\right)$ and $P_2=Q_2=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & 1 \end{array}\right)$. We have

$trace(P_1Q_1)=trace(P_2Q_2)=2+\frac{1}{2} > 2 = trace\left(\frac{P_1+P_2}{2}\frac{Q_1+Q_2}{2} \right)$.

Therefore the function $f(P,Q)=trace(PQ)$ cannot be quasi-concave.

Comment: Sorry. It should be concave. In the scalar case, the function is quasi-concave. I have edited the questions.

Comment: The question is quasi-concave, and your answer can only check the concave or convex, not quasi-concave.